# JQXMenu Databind with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application where I need to fetch the menu items from a text file.
I am new to JQX.
But while displaying the records its showing nothing.

## My Text File(LeftMenu.txt) as below:

```
[{
 "text": "Menu1",
                "id": "1",
                    "parentid": "-1"
 }, 

{
 "text": "Menu2",
                "id": "2",
                    "parentid": "-1"
},

{
 "text": "Menu3",
                "id": "3",
                    "parentid": "-1"
 }
]
```

==========================================================================

## The code is here under

```
// prepare the data for Left Menu
        var urlleftpanel = "../../Public/sampledata/leftmenu.txt";

        var sourceleftmenu =
              {
                  datatype: "json",
                  datafields: [
                               { name: 'id' },
                               { name: 'parentid' },
                               { name: 'text' }
                  ],
                  id: 'id',
                  url: urlleftpanel
              };

        // create data adapter.
        var dataAdapter1 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(sourceleftmenu);
       // perform Data Binding.
        dataAdapter1.dataBind();        

        var records = dataAdapter1.getRecordsHierarchy('id', 'parentid', 'items', [{   name: 'text', map: 'label' }]);
        var records = da.records;
        $('#jqxWidget').jqxMenu({ source: records , height: 53, theme: theme, width: '95px' });
```

=====================================================================================
Please Help its very urgent

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting async: false in the source object.

```
 var sourceleftmenu =
              {
                  datatype: "json",
                  async: false,
                  datafields: [
                               { name: 'id' },
                               { name: 'parentid' },
                               { name: 'text' }
                  ],
                  id: 'id',
                  url: urlleftpanel
              };
```